# Tizen for Wearable SDK 1.0.0 - prevent default event when pressing 'power'

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-emulator

Is it possible to prevent the default event of exiting the current application when the power button is pressed?

So far I only managed to add functionality to the 'back' and 'menu' hwkeys but pressing the 'power' button on the emulator ignores the eventlistener for 'tizenhwkey' and exists the application.